# Show that a Lissajous curve has incommesurate frequencies iff it isdense in a rectangle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If we have a Lissajous curve given by the parametric equations
$$x(t)=A\sin(\omega_x t)$$
$$y(t)=B\sin(\omega_y t + \delta),$$

how can we show that the curve is dense in the rectangle of sides $A,B$ if and only if $\omega_x$ and $\omega_y$ are incommensurate (i.e. their ratio is irrational)?

What I tried:
Suppose it is not dense, so there exists a neighborhood of radius $r$ around some $x_0$, $y_0$ through which the curve doesn't pass. Since the parametric functions are continuous in time, a neighborhood of size $r$ in distance translates to some neighborhood of size $\tau$ in time.

The curve is at $x=x_0$ at the times
$$t_x=\{\frac{1}{\omega_x}\left[\sin^{-1}(x_0/A)+2n\pi\right]|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$
and at $y=y_0$ at the times

$$t_x=\{\frac{1}{\omega_y}\left[\sin{-1}(y_0/B)-\delta+2m\pi\right]|m\in \mathbb N\}.$$

If any two points in in the sets $t_x, t_y$ are less than $\tau$ away, then the trajectory goes through the $r$-neighborhood around $x_0,y_0$, giving a contradiction. For this we need to find integers $m,n$ such that
$$\frac{\sin^{-1}(x_0/A)}{2\pi\omega_x} - \frac{\sin^{-1}(y_0/B)-\delta}{2\pi\omega_y}+\frac{n}{\omega_x}-\frac{m}{\omega_y}<\tau$$
At this point it seems that I need something tat states that the difference $n/\omega_x - m/\omega_y$ can be arbitrarily close to any real if $\omega_x$ and $\omega_y$ are incommensurate, but I have not been able to prove anything like that.

Comment: I haven't carefully read your solution, but here's an alternative strategy: "Lift" to the curve $$t \mapsto (A\cos(\omega_{x}t), A\sin(\omega_{x}t), B\cos(\omega_{y}t + \delta), B\sin(\omega_{y}t + \delta))$$in the torus $S^{1}(A) \times S^{1}(B)$ and use (or establish) the analogous property for [lines of (ir)rational slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_winding_of_a_torus) (where you can bring the universal covering to bear); then project to the plane of the second and fourth coordinates to get your Lissajous figure.