# Completed Proof For Incommensurate Lissajous Curves/Bowditch Curves Are Dense In The Rectangle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, ergodic-theory

A Lissajous curve, or a Bowditch curve, is given by the parametric equations

$x(t)=Asin(ω_{x}t + \phi)$

$y(t)=Bsin(ω_{y}t+δ)$,

Now if $\frac{\omega_{x}}{\omega_{y}}$ is irrational, and $\phi$ and $\delta$ are fixed, then the set $\mathcal{L} = (x(t), y(t) | -\infty < t < \infty)$ is supposedly dense in the rectangle $R =[-A,A]$x$[-B,B]$

I have seen:

[Show that a Lissajous curve has incommesurate frequencies iff it isdense in a rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901546/show-that-a-lissajous-curve-has-incommesurate-frequencies-iff-it-isdense-in-a-re)

But a completed proof was not given. This problem is frequently mentioned in the literature, but a reference to a full proof is never given. Does anyone have such a reference, or could someone provide a proof here?

Answer (score 2):

You can write $x$ and $y$ in complex number with the exponentials (easiest way): $\mathbf r\left(t\right)=\left(Ae^{ω_{x}t + \phi},Be^{ω_{y}t + \delta}\right)$. Then proof it by induction, suppose that there is a period $T\neq0$ so that $\mathbf r\left(t\right)=\mathbf r\left(t+T\right)$.

Comment: This doesn't proof that the period is dense rather it proves it's not periodic